# share login/logout sessions across two installs?

Tags: multisite, login, session, logout

I'm having some issues sharing the user sessions across two installs.

(a) site on http://stolenmx.com
(b) site on http://arcade.stolenmx.com

I have installed B in the same database as A and I have defined the user and user_meta tables so I am sharing user data and users etc but I can't seem to bridge the sessions.

I have tried using cookies a few different ways but nothing works.

This is what I'm using in (b) wp-config at the moment with no effect,

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'www.stolenmx.com');
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
```

does anyone know how to get this working?

I'm actually using UserPro on site (a) to manage registration and login and I have wp-login.php disabled. Could this be why cookie isn't working cause UserPro saves the cookie elsewhere or just simply doesn't use one?

Comment: Have you tried cookie domain `stolenmx.com`? (without the `www`) And make sure the security keys in both your config files all match.

Comment: Hey, yep, I have done this but it has no effect on either site. I coppied the salts etc so they match and tried changing the cookie domain but nothing?

Comment: Try `.stolenmx.com` - notice the dot prefix.

Comment: Tried it mate, no difference.

Comment: Found the culprit, see answer.

Answer (score 5):

You also need to define a matching `COOKIEHASH` for both sites - a random 32 bit string will do.

By default, `COOKIEHASH` is an MD5 hash of the site URL, and is used to generate the default names for all authentication-related cookies. Hence why, at the moment, your cross-domain login isn't working (the names of the cookies aren't consistent, as `COOKIEHASH` will be different for each site).

See [`wp_cookie_constants()`](http://wpseek.com/function/wp_cookie_constants/) for more information.

So to recap, your `wp-config.php` for both sites should look like:

```
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.stolenmx.com' ); // Dot prefix
define( 'COOKIEPATH',    '/' );
define( 'COOKIEHASH',    md5( 'stolenmx.com' ) );

define( 'CUSTOM_USER_TABLE',      'wp_users' );
define( 'CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', 'wp_usermeta' );
```

Comment: How would i define it? just add this to both wp-config.php?

    $cookiehash = md5("http://stolenmx.com");        
    define('COOKIEHASH', $cookiehash );

Comment: Yes, that'll do :)

Comment: Perfect bud, I will try it right now and let you know in about 3 mins if it works :)

Comment: Okay so it kind of works lol, when I login to site (b) I'm also logged into site (a) but when I logout of (b) it doesn't log me out of (a)? 

however when logging in to site (a) it doesn't log me in to site (b). 

So all that's working is logging into site (b). Any ideas?

Comment: See my revision. Make sure you're testing in a clean browser (i.e. completely wipe history/cookies). I can't offer much more help, it works for me!

Comment: Okay, so I now have it working ALMOST lol I had to define the MD5 COOKEHASH. The only problem I have now is that when I log out from site (b) it doesn't log out from site (a)! 

login works, so if i login to site (a) it logs in to (b) and vice versa, and If i logout from site (a) it logs me out from site (b) it's only when I logout from (b) it doesn't log me out from (a)? 

Make sense? lol

Answer (score 1):

In addition to TheDeadMedic's answer, both sites must share the same keys and salts in the wp-config.php files (I replaced the string with four zeros):

```
define('AUTH_KEY',         '0000');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  '0000');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    '0000');
define('NONCE_KEY',        '0000');
define('AUTH_SALT',        '0000');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', '0000');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   '0000');
define('NONCE_SALT',       '0000');
```

I created a blog post about this which has more details: https://www.tekfused.com/wordpress/sharing-login-cookies-among-wordpress-installs/