# can we share user login in 2 wordpress installs in 2 subdomains on one server?

Tags: cookies, shared-user-tables

We have 2 WordPress sites in 2 different sub-domains like **test1.abc.com** and **test2.abc.com** . Both sites have **wp-require** plugin activated and only logged-in users can see the site. We want to make a system where if a user logged into one site, he should be auto-login into the other one.

**What I did:**

After some searching I know I need to use one database for both sites. So I have done these steps:

1. I have download the whole database of **test2.abc.com** site and change all prefix `wp_` to `wpmo_`, replace it in whole database and upload it into first site's database.
2. I added these 2 lines in `wp-config.php` of the second site, to define that second site should use first site's user table not its own one.

   ```
    define('CUSTOM_USERMETA_TABLE', 'wp_usermeta');
    define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'wp_users');
   ```
3. Now, the second site is using the first site's users and I am able to login to the second site by the user details of first site.
4. The next problem is cookies, so I added these lines in `wp-config` of both sites.

   ```
   define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.abc.com');
   define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
   ```
5. Now I logged in into  **test1.abc.com** and when I go to **test2.abc.com** , it asks me to login. That means cookies are not passing from the first site to the second one.

Both subdomains are on same server and sharing same database user table.

I know it is a cookie issue and I have gone through many articles on that, but they all talk about sharing cookies between a domain and its subdomains. Here I am having 2 subdomains.

Comment: Are you actually using [WordPress Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Multisite), or have you got two *separate* WordPress installations? (It sounds like the latter.)

Comment: yes, it is the later one.

Answer (score 1):

See [my answer on this exact problem](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/183750/1685). Long story short, you also need to define `COOKIEHASH`, otherwise the login cookie names will be different for each site:

```
define( 'COOKIEHASH', 'randomhash' );
```

Make sure to change `randomhash` to a real hash, you can [grab one here](http://md5.my-addr.com/online_random_md5_hash_generator-and-md5_random_hash.php).

Comment: Hi @TheDeadMedic , this one really helpful. but now when i go to second website, it says "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."

Comment: You're using the same database for both installs right? Each will have a different table prefix - you need to find `{table_prefix_site_1}_capabilities` in the user meta table and clone it, changing the key to `{table_prefix_site_2}_capabilities`

Comment: now when i try it on my actual websites, its not working :( . now i login to first site and than go to second, its not auto login. however , when i come back to first site and refresh, it also get logged out automatically. i have added this code in both wp-config.php file.    define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'wp_users');
    define('CUSTOM_USERMETA_TABLE', 'wp_usermeta');
    define('COOKIEHASH', 'aee53c017c29dc0d3ae37253fc8cbfd8');
    define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.techstriker.com');
    define('COOKIEPATH', '/');

Answer (score 0):

Hi Multisite User Management plugin will help you

https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-user-management/

Comment: multisite is not an option for me, thanks for help.