# Share login status across subdomains without network

Tags: login, subdomains, cookies

I need to share login status across subdomains in one install. For example, after I login in main site: localhost/dx/, but when I visit test.localhost/dx/ (I remove 'redirect_canonical' to stop automatically redirecting to main site), it's the same page, but I'm not logged in. I figured that it's the cookie problem, I tried to set

```
 define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.loclhost'); // or loclhost
 define('COOKIEPATH', '/');  
 define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '/');
```

but still not remain logged in subdomains.

[image]

Anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [share login/logout sessions across two installs?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183720/share-login-logout-sessions-across-two-installs)

Comment: I'm afraid not. It's one install and not multisite.

Comment: then edit your question and include all details. no one here is mind reader

Comment: .... and obviously you should use multisite. Use wordpress as it is intended to be used and you will delay your heart attack by at least 10 years.

Comment: There are thousands of subdomains in this project, using mu will create thousands of database tables.

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this code:

After installation, open the `wp-config.php` file in Site B's installation root, and add (or replace) the following lines shortly after the database configuration, modifying them as needed to fit your configuration:

```
$cookiehash = md5("http://www.example.com/");  // Use Site A's URL

define(CUSTOM_USER_TABLE,'wp_users');           //Change 'wp' to match the prefix set during
define(CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE,'wp_usermeta');   //  Site A's installation
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');                      //This path should reference Site A's root
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '/');                  //Should match 'COOKIEPATH'
define('COOKIEHASH', $cookiehash );
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I added
$cookiehash = md5("http://localhost/dx/");  // Use Site A's URL

define(CUSTOM_USER_TABLE,'sa1x_users');           //Change 'wp' to match the prefix set during
define(CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE,'sa1x_usermeta');   //  Site A's installation
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');                      //This path should reference Site A's root
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '/');                  //Should match 'COOKIEPATH'
define('COOKIEHASH', $cookiehash );

Now I can't log in. Please note this is not network.